# How to add modules in cart page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using opencart 2.3.0.2,

i want to add featured product in cart page,

in admin layouts there is no cart page layout to add.
how to add modules like featured product, related product etc., in cart page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add that layout with name for example `cart` and add route `checkout/cart`. Now you can add your modules to this page.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm sooo stupid, i didn't see add layout option